# Asp.net core Localization not pickup others culture except English

Tags: localization, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-localization, routelocalization-mvc

I'm building an application Asp.net core 1.1 with localization by URL.

I uploaded the solution to https://github.com/hoangnguyenxuan/Spouse/tree/master/VoiConShop

Everything is running without any errors. However, It's just English culture running now.
If this is illegal for just posting the link of solution, I'll post code here.

Please help me, I'm going to be mad now.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just tried your solution and it works as expected. If I replace the url with /en, /ee or /ru on the home page, I get the expected translation that's provided by **@CustomLocalizer["HelloWorld"]**. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks @Pereira , do you mean the solution is running as expected? Did you modify something?

Comment: I've just check the solution. It's running as well now. I don't know reason why it runs now. The question should be deleted.

Comment: I upgraded Asp.net Core 1.1 to 2.0.2 after I'd posted this question. So it works as expectation now. Cause may be version of Asp.net Core

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I didn't upgrade the solution, just commented out Google and Facebook authentication because no ClientId was found...